# Present a popover on button tap in Swift

Tags: swift3

I would like to make a popover from a button tap. but when I click on my button, my popover cover all my page. where is my problem?

@IBAction func buttonTap(sender: UIButton) {

```
    // get a reference to the view controller for the popover
    let popController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popoverId")

    // set the presentation style
    popController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover

    // set up the popover presentation controller
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender // button
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds

    // present the popover
    self.present(popController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Have you ensured the parent view of your popup doesn't have opaque set to true?

Comment: Yes, i have confirmed that there's doesn't have opaque set to true

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the modalPresentaionStyle

```
popController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

Comment: I assume the parent view on the popup is completely transparent